# Translating a Wordpress Plugin which relies on content from an API

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, translation

I have a Wordpress plugin that creates a form based on questions/form fields from an API. So I don't know how many questions there will be in my form but I will know the types of questions they will be.

So I have PHP code which runs like: for each question in the API call create a form field. So all this is working great. However some users would like my plugin translated into their language. I know how to do all this for typical translations, for example there's an excellent tutorial about how to do this here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/translating-wordpress-plugins/ which in summary is just doing this: `<?php $greeting = __( 'Hello There!', 'text-domain' ); ?>` and setting up your po files etc.

The problem I obviously have is that I have a loop which is getting questions from the API so I can't do something like this:

```
foreach($jsondataform['fields'] as $field){
echo '<label>'.__( $field['field'] , 'text-domain' ).'</label>';
}
```

Because then every field label will be called the same thing. As I mentioned I will know all the questions that can possibly come from the api (there's around 10 in total) but I don't how which ones will be called. So I don't know how to make this translation work. What I am starting to think now is having a settings section for my plugin which will allow the user to put in custom text for all 10 possible questions and then using jquery/javascript over-riding whatever text is output onto the screen.

Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to put some more content/code.

Comment: Thanks Tejas, I am more looking for a methodology not so much a full code answer.

The more I am researching this it looks like I can't put variables into translations so some over-ride technique is required whether that be through jQuery/PHP.